# Kivy/Python: NameError name 'fcn' not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, kivy

I'm not sure why I am getting a NameError when my code contains the same name? Here's the code. I believe that the weightValue should pass from onBtnPress to fcn(). Is there something i'm missing here?

The error 
[NameError: name 'fcn' is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDh4j.png)

```
weightValue = ""
class keypad(App):

    def onBtnPress(self, btn):
        global weightValue

        if btn.text == "Clear":
            weightValue = weightValue[:-10]

        elif btn.text == "Enter":
            print("the value has be sent")
            #send value to weight calculator

        else:
            weightValue = weightValue + btn.text
            fcn(weightValue)
            #send value to label

    def fcn(self, weightValue):
        print(weightValue)


    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        # , spacing=15, padding=15, row_default_height=40
        # Make the background gray:
        with layout.canvas.before:
                Color(.2,.2,.2,1)
                self.rect = Rectangle(size=(800,600), pos=layout.pos)

        leftBox = GridLayout(cols=2)

        lblweight = Label(text='Weight in pounds: ')
        weightValuelbl = Label(text=weightValue)

        leftBox.add_widget(lblweight)

        leftBox.add_widget(weightValuelbl)


        rightBox = GridLayout(cols=3)

        _list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "Clear", 0, "Enter"]
        for num in _list:
            rightBox.add_widget(Button(text=str(num), on_release=self.onBtnPress))

        layout.add_widget(leftBox)
        layout.add_widget(rightBox)

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keypad().run()
```

Comment: You have to call `self.fct`, as it is a method of your class, not a free function.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to call a general *function* `fcn`, but there is no such function.  You do have an *instance method* by that name, but that is not what you called.  Please review your tutorial on classes and methods.  You need to do one of two things to fix this usage:

Call your instance method properly, such as

```
self.fcn(weightValue)
```

-- or --

Move function `fcn` outside the class, where it will become a "normal" function.

Note that you haven't used `self` in the function in any way; why is `fcn` inside the class at all?  As the previous answer noted, since all you've done is to make this a restricted (single-value) call to `print`, it seems to serve no useful purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! Ya, my knowledge of classes and methods is weak.